# How do Han and Chewie find Rey and Finn in the Millennium Falcon?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*, Rey and Finn hide under one of the floor panels of the Falcon while they prepare to release poisonous gas. Han somehow finds them before they can release it.

How was Han able to find them so fast?

Comment: Because it was the same trick he used when the DS1 picked up the Falcon.

Comment: Rey dropped something and made a noise.

Comment: Note regarding phantom42's comment: Same *trick*, different *location*. Rey and Finn weren't hiding in the aftermarket secret compartments, there were merely hiding in a mantenance bay. That was the same bay in which Chewie and Han spend some time working in *Empire*. The maintenance bay has a slotted panel that covers it, while the secret compartments have smooth, polished floor panels on top.

Comment: It's the *Falcon*. Han and Chewie know exactly where every compartment where something can be smuggled in is because *they put them there*.

Comment: @Shadur - But how did he know which compartment to check first?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to the film's [junior novel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(junior_novelization)), it was because Rey didn't put the deck plate back down properly:

> *Her current operators weren’t hard to find. A deck plate in the lounge
>   wasn’t flush with the floor. Chewbacca tore it free and Han pointed
>   his blaster at two youths—a male and female, both human—and a
>   newfangled round-modeled droid. The youths raised their hands in
>   surrender.*

We actually see this in the film, although it's not made especially obvious:

[image]

Comment: This time you can't complain. Someone went through and downvoted **ALL 3 later answers**. AND the question. I suspect it's a Resistance spy. Or an escaped rathtar

Comment: @DVK - But mine has a picture. A picture, dammit!

Comment: technically, yours has a still. A picture would take far more time to paint than it took you to post.

Comment: How do you get a image(still) of a movie still in theaters?

Comment: @John - I drew it from memory. That's actually a painting.

Comment: Well in that case it would indeed be a picture, not a still

Comment: @John - That's [what I said](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113777/how-do-han-and-chewie-find-rey-and-finn-in-the-millennium-falcon/113788?noredirect=1#comment274159_113788)

Comment: Rathtars certainly have enough limbs to do lots of simultaneous downvoting...

Answer (score 44):

In the film, one can hear a sound of metal on metal just before Han and Chewie turn their attention to the floor panel. It sounds as if Rey or Finn dropped a tool on the floor. Alternately, the sound effect might be intended to represent the sounds of actually tampering with the gas line. In either case, it seems like Han and Chewie both overheard this sound, and they know the layout of the Falcon well enough to tell that it came from the compartments beneath the flooring.

Comment: (I was confused about this as well the first time I watched the film, but it seemed to stand out on second viewing)

Comment: Just saw it again last night. There was definitely a noise.

Answer (score 11):

According to the WGA script, **they simply split up and went to check**.

> HAN
>   Chewie, we're home. 
>   **Han gives Chewie a nod to check out the ship.**
>   Chewie heads off one way, Han in another.
>   The grating above LIFTS OFF
>   -- hands in surrender, they look up at Han, who's training his blaster on them, threatening.
>   They're SCARED.

Which makes sense:

- The Falcon is a small ship
- Han knows it like the back of his hand. Or better
- And the Secret compartments under the floor are **all on one place**, at the center of the ship

[image: map of the Millenium Falcon]

Comment: Secret compartments or maintenance/repair bay? Remember Rey was trying to fix the *Falcon* and I don't recall Finn or Rey discovering the secret compartments. I'm talking about this: http://img.lum.dolimg.com/v1/images/tool_a206209a.jpeg?width=666 It's in the floor, has a slotted ceiling panel, and is the site of several repair attempts. Also R2 falls into it after he re-activates the hyperdrive in *Empire*.

Comment: The secret compartments are different. Compare Richard's image to: http://www.curbsideclassic.com/wp-content/comment-image/274358.png

Comment: I'm pretty sure the hole behind R2 in this picture is where they were hiding: http://a.dilcdn.com/bl/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2015/04/Screen-Shot-2015-04-14-at-10.58.59-AM.jpg which would put it between the technical station and the "step up" in the diagram in your answer.