# What is the intended crew complement of the Millennium Falcon?

Tags: star-wars, millennium-falcon

The Millennium Falcon has changed hands several times.  In the *Star Wars* film saga, we mainly see it being used by small crews for clandestine purposes: smuggling, rescuing princesses, and destroying Death Stars.

**In normal commercial operation, how many crew members would a YT-1300 light freighter like the Millennium Falcon have?**

Comment: [This link](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/YT-1300_light_freighter/Legends) mentions 2, with a minimal crew of 1... Although I find that pretty hard to believe since you'd have a pilot, copilot, and up to 2 gunners (if you need them)... So 4-ish? I guess it depends on what you're doing...

Comment: @DangerZone- to be very specific, this is a Wookiepedia (user generated Wiki) and the crew #s on that page **are not sourced at all**, which means chances are, someone made that datum up, based on the fact that we see a crew of 2 in the films.

Comment: Although, they DO give a sourced (from " Millennium Falcon Owner's Workshop Manual") number of passengers as 6-15.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Per an image DVK posted in [another answer of his](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/113785/348), the Falcon "sleeps 7".
[image: Millenium Falcon schematic drawing]

(There are two rooms with triple bunks in them, and there's an additional bunk next to the lounge seat.)

However, we all know that a tent that "sleeps N" will only **fit** N - *x* actual human adults, where *x* is between 2 and N-1. The same seems to be true of the Falcon, because -- as the schematic also shows -- there are only 4 vacuum suits provided, and more critically, only 5 oxygen masks.

It's possible that the vacuum suits are for EVA work, rather than emergencies, so there is no need to provide one for every crew member. However, it seems to me that on a spaceship, oxygen masks serve the same function as life preservers on boats: in the event of an emergency, they provide a little bit of life support. (In both cases, the cold will kill you before the lack of oxygen/buoyancy will, but let's not talk about such morbid things.)

So, at least according to this schematic, the *maximum* crew complement of the Falcon is **5**, at least for a responsible captain; an irresponsible captain (whose crew is not up to date on the specifications of the ship, and/or breathes something other than oxygen anyway) can employ as many as 6 people, for a total crew of **7**. *The Force Awakens* showed that the *minimum* required to fly it is **2**, because there are vital controls that you can't reach from the pilot's seat.

Comment: Does the crew of a spaceship like this really have any reasonable chance of survival in an emergency, even with an oxygen mask?

Comment: @KRyan: probably not, but then again, what's a life preserver gonna do for you in the middle of the ocean? Besides "absolutely nothing", that is? :)

Comment: Awsome find!!!!

Comment: @Martha - it will make you **feel** safer and less panicked

Comment: "The Force Awakens showed that the minimum required to fly it is 2", unless, of course, you are Luke Skywalker. Then you can fly it and fire the guns as well, all by yourself.

Comment: @Kevin: when does Luke ever fly the Falcon?

Comment: @Martha  I believe it was in "The Courtship of Princess Leia"

Comment: I guess the last two bunks are for the people you plan on feeding to rathtars?

Comment: @Martha Give you time to contemplate and reflect on your life in your final moments, as well as provide a calming shimmer of hope that you might be rescued.

Comment: What about hotbunking?

Comment: @Joe: it's a freighter, not a navy ship. People who aren't subject to military discipline are not gonna be happy without some personal space to their name - some place where they can leave their stuff without anyone else mucking around with it.

Comment: ESB shows the minimum required pilots as one, even while conducting evasive maneuvers. Leia drives; C3PO watches and complains.

Comment: @Kevin I was thinking that was in the Truce at Bakura. Reading through the plot summaries on Wikipedia, neither mentions it. Courtship seems more likely based on what I read there though.

Comment: @DCShannon, it's been a long time since I read it, but I'm thinking it's towards the end of TCOPL when Luke almost dies from the force-witches attacks, but then gets a "mega-boost" of the Force from all the life on the planet

Comment: What are the odds that any in-universe technical drawings show the secret compartments?

Comment: @Kevin - Yes, it is.  Mostly done through the force.

Comment: "The Force Awakens showed that the minimum required to fly it is 2" - actually before picking up Rey and Finn's unconscious body, Chewie is seen flying the Falcon solo.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake Chewie has much longer reach than Rey :)

Comment: +0: AFAIK, `x` is between 0 and N-1; I've had both a 2 people and 1 person tent, and both worked well with `x == 0`

Comment: "the cold will kill you" Wouldn't it be (your own body) heat in space? Vacuums are extremely good insulators. Though I suppose you could have a situation where oxygen supplies run out but air pressure is maintained.

Comment: *there are only 4 vacuum suits provided, and more critically, only 5 oxygen masks.* I would assume the vacuum suits provide oxygen too. So in a pinch, you could use a vacuum suit if five of your colleagues have already nabbed the masks. Hope you can get it on quick enough!

Comment: @vaxquis: for the type of camping we do, 1 and 2 person tents never even come into consideration. (If you can't stand up in it, forget it.) So in that sense, my equation holds: if N - x comes out negative or 0, then the tent is too small to be useful. For reference, [this](http://www.medievalfantasiesco.com/Camping/Mediev39.jpg) is very similar to my current tent. (The same calculations hold for scout camps, though. Basically, the "sleeps N" numbers don't take people's *stuff* into consideration.)

Comment: I suppose it doesn't make *real* sense for there to be some disconnect between the number of oxygen masks and the number of bunks, but it *could* be expected that you might be carrying persons who must bring their own life-support due to breathing a different type of atmosphere.

Comment: @Martha just because it's not into consideration for *you* doesn't make it so for everybody... saying `we all know XYZ` and later adding `for the type of camping we do... so in that sense, [it] holds` reminds me heavily that [many people say that some {weasel words} ain't OK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word).

Comment: @Martha While you are right that "sleeps N" doesn't take people's stuff into consideration *for tents*, the Falcon is a cargo ship. I don't think that place for stuff is a problem, the diagram even shows storage lockers.

Comment: @offbyoni: Oh, come on. It's not that hard. The Falcon only has 5 oxygen masks, but 7 bunks. So I'm drawing a semi-joking *analogy* between it and the way tents are marketed. It's an *analogy*, not an *equivalence*. Sheesh.

Comment: Great answer, @Martha.  :-)

Answer (score 29):

Based on the Falcon's schematics, it would be between 2 and 6 depending on mission profile:

1. Can't be more than 6. [Falcon's schematics](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/8/81/Millennium_Falcon_Old_Layout.JPG/revision/latest?cb=20070217101945) show two 3-bunk rooms. **And more importantly, only one head**.
2. Can't be less than 2.

   - *The Force Awakens* clearly shows (especially novelization text) that 1 person simply can't operate the Falcon - you can't even reach the shield controls from Pilot seat (which is why Rey's initial maneuvers on Jakku were so weird - she was trying to reach while flying)
   - The Force Awakens Incredible Cross-Sections page 35 says Falcon's crew minimum is 2
3. If money is no object, 4 people for a possibly-risky mission seems the minimum: Pilot, Copilot, and 2 people to man the top and bottom turrets. *TFA Incredible cross-sections* page 35 shows "Engineering Station"; which means an intended full complement includes an engineer, which makes properly crewed ship would have 5 or 6 crew.

Comment: I concur that a maximum combat complement would be 7 (pilot, copilot, 2 flight deck techs, 2 gunners, engineer), plus repair droids.  And the mod-ability of the YT-1300 series means it's possible to replace something (like cargo capacity) with another bunk room.

Comment: @CodeswithHammer Or sleep in shifts. You'd need at least three pilots (each sleeps while the other two fly), for that matter, for a long-haul mission, same for gunners if it's through hostile territory.

Comment: +1 for "pilots shouldn't be allowed anywhere near the hyperdrive"

Comment: In military, full crew complement is often 3 times the number of bunk beds, because of shifts.

Comment: Assuming you're just flying it from A to B, then the shields may be unnecessary, hence a 1 person crew would be possible although I agree not optimal.

Comment: @Random832: For normal service, I believe the intended complement would be 3 people, for the reason you state.  Any more, and they take up mass and volume that could be given over to self-loading freight.

Comment: Might be interesting to dig up how many where *seen* flying it in RoJ.

Comment: I would argue that requiring at least two people to fly is a specific quirk of the Falcon and not a general rule for that class of ship. The Falcon was shown to be heavily modified and full of shoestring repairs in the original films, and one can only assume it has gotten worse since then. The whole purpose of HAVING a co-pilot is so that you have someone to operate the ship if the pilot is incapacitated or simply has to leave the cockpit for some reason. No sane designer would create a ship with vital controls inaccessible to the pilot.

Answer (score 13):

The [Millennium Falcon Owners Workshop Manual](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Millennium-Falcon-Manual-Corellian-Freighter/dp/0857330969/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1452102678&sr=8-1&keywords=millennium%20falcon%20owners%20manual) shows the *Falcon* as being a YT-1300f (the dedicated freight variant, others are the passenger transport YT-1300p, and YT-1300fp which is a mix of the two). For all variants of the YT-1300  the listed crew complement is two, however the number of passengers varies from model to model - for the f and fp models 6 passengers can be carried, the p version carries 9-15 passengers.

Comment: Any direct source for that passenger number of 6? It seems odd considering the diagram Martha posted which only shows 5 oxygen masks in the 'passenger' lounge. There also appear to be five spaces on the acceleration couch. To me that would indicate a max capacity of 8, pilot, copilot, and gunner (who presumably have emergency life support at their stations) plus up to five passengers or off-duty crew.

Answer (score 10):

A quick note to people counting either beds or seats, that will likely lead you to the wrong conclusion.

If you applied that to a nuclear submarine, you would drastically underestimate the number of crew, because people work shifts and share bunks (US navy terminology is hot bunking).

So there are minimum 3 pilots, rotating between

Pilot's Chair
Co-pilot's chair
bed 1

There will be 2 gunners, but these are unlikely to spend more than a few hours a week in the gunnery chairs. They will share bed 2, but otherwise mess about playing that chesslike game when the ship is not under attack. Only 2 are needed, not 3 because they only have to pay attention so infrequently, unlike pilots who must both be at the wheel at all times in a ship that obeys regulations.

I would suggest there is likely to be 2 engineers as well, who can share bed 3. This will allow someone to always be manning the engine room, as well 8 man hours per day for repairs (16 hour work days).

This leaves us with 3 additional bunks in 1 room.

Depending on how these are hot bunked, they could support 1 selfish captain, 3 passengers in relative comfort, or up to 9 crew if they were required.

The Falcon, obeying sensible precautions, would host 8-16 people at all times.

Comment: It's not exactly a warship though, even though it does have 2 quad laser cannons, it's classed as a "freighter". Do crew hotbunk in a freighter?

Comment: Gun turrets notwithstanding, the Falcon is a freighter, not a military vehicle. While there are some long-haul truckers who use sleeper cabs to be able to switch drivers and stay on the road for extended periods, most truckers drive alone. Also, can you imagine Han letting some hireling pilot the Falcon while he takes a nap?

Comment: Pilots definitely hotbunk in passenger airplanes, I can only assume they do in long haul cargo planes. The distinction between Fighter and Freighter seems to be a bit more blurred in Star Wars, due to the relative lawlessness of certain sections of the galaxy, the isolation and the need for protection.

By intended crew complement, I was refering to the intentions of the Correlian Designers of the ship, and the regulators that they would have listened to. Obviously, Han is unlikely to keep the recommended crew.

Comment: @Octopus Well I wouldn't want to hot bunk with Chewbacca.  Imagine the shed fur all over it, not to mention the mattress would be all saggy from his size! :)

Comment: @JaneS not to mention the risk of still being in *his* bunk when he wants a nap. (sure its a "shared" bunk.. but you want to argue?)

Comment: @gbjbaanb Not me!  I like my arms attached!

Comment: The gun turrets of the *Falcon* are non-standard, if I remember the RPG background material correctly. A stock YT-1300f had only light lasers for anti-asteroid / debris work, not the rapid-firing quad-mediums of the *Falcon*. (I *love* hearing the oooomph of them in *New Hope*, for sure.)

Comment: @Martha: As nobody else has answered your question, I will:  Heck no!  Han won't let anybody else other than Chewie pilot the _Falcon_ as long as he has any say in the matter, under any conditions.  Not even via slave circuit for a precision in-system jump (which happened in the Thrawn trilogy).

Comment: @CodeswithHammer while your sentiment is clearly correct, Han practically begs Lando to take the Falcon into battle over Endor, so there are a very select few people he trusts to fly her.

Answer (score 1):

In [Star Wars: The Old Republic](http://swtor.com), smuggler characters get a Corellian as their home ship. By the end of the game you have 5 permanent companions living on the ship with you (plus a protocol driod). Each has their own room on the ship they hang out in. There are currently ways to acquire 2 more, but I've never done that so I don't know if they have places on the ship as well.

That makes this somewhat consistent with the other blueprint-based answers that have the upper limit in the vicinity of 5-7 crew.

I doubt this is canon of course, but a lot of the details in the blueprint in those other answers probably isn't canon anymore either.

Comment: The ship in SWTOR is an XS Freighter, not a YT-1300. Aside from that, it's also from a period hundreds of years earlier than the YT-1300.

Comment: @TylerH - A very good point. There's probably no good reason why one wouldn't be a scaled-up or down version of the other, such that the amount of crew supported would change without changing the overall look of the ship.

Answer (score 0):

In *Return of the Jedi* there are two soldiers doing nearly nothing during the Battle of Endor behind Lando and Nien Nunb. Nevertheless, Lando seemed to feel the need to staff those two seats so they must of had some purpose. Since it was a intense battle I can't imagine they didn't also have two gunners - though we don't really see those guns firings. Lets assume those guns were staffed.

So for a combat mission I would say the minimum ideal staffing would be 6 people with each person having a very specific purpose. For a non-combat mission such a crew would be wasteful (salaries, food, crowding, etc) and the crew would each serve a broader set of duties.

The gunner, for example, would only be a gunner for a few rare moments they are in a pinch and spends most of his time attending to the cargo, serving as a navigator, cleaning the head, or otherwise. It would be pretty dumb to drag a rarely used gunner around the galaxy just to sit around and play holochess most of the time.

In various Star Wars scenes it is almost always "all hands on deck" when there is a crisis so I can not imagine how just Han and Chewie can stay alive (lucky, I guess) when its just the two of them - clearly that is not enough. If you asked Han it would be three. Notice how he offered Rey a job but not Finn (he also offered Luke a job in Episode IV, 'member?).

**So Han views the ideal crew as three for general smuggling operations while Lando would say six is the ideal crew for a battle.**